# Regex with new line character is matching string

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor

I've got a regex expression in a Mongo Meteor query:

```
  Programs.find({ Notes: { $regex: '^((?!REFUNDED).)*$' }}).fetch()
```

This should read, 'Return all documents where the 'Notes' field (a string field) doesn't contain the string "REFUNDED"'.

I'm finding a problem when the text in the Notes field contains a new line character '\n'. When it does find a new line character, it renders the statement true.

For example, if document 1's Notes field was the string "Line one. \nLine two", document 1 would not be returned, even though "REFUNDED" isn't in the string.

What's the best way around this?

Comment: Use `[\s\S]` or `[^]` (in JavaScript) instead of `.`. You can also pass the [`s` option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_options) to MongoDB so that `.` matches `\n`

Comment: I tried $regex: '^((?!REFUNDED).)*$', $options: 's' with no luck. I was unable to get your [\s\s] or [^] to work either.

Comment: `[\s\S]` not `[\s\s]`

Comment: Correction, your [^] replacement for '.' does work. I was working with the wrong file. Thanks.